# Is there a limit to how many characters in a row getchar can scan?

Tags: c, stdio, getchar

I have an assignment to make a program that calculates the iterative digital sum of an integer, eg. doing the digital sum until the result is a single digit. The catch is that the number they test for are much greater that can be stored in any int type (around 10^40000) so my idea was to do the first sum using getchar(), adding up the number digit by digit.
My code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    long int n=0;
    int c;

    //first sum
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'){
        n+=(c-'0');
    }

    //iterative summing
    long int s;
    do{
        s=0;
        while(n>0){
            s+=n%10;
            n/=10;
        }
        n=s;
    }while (n>=10);

    printf("%ld\n",s);
    return 0;
}
```

It worked for relatively short numbers, however after some point, the sum would come out wrong. So I tried setting up a variable that'd get incremented with each character summed, and it would always show the number of 4095.

So my question is, is there an 11-bit limit to how many characters you can get from stdin using getchar()? If so, is there a way to get more?

Comment: Well, you could take it in as a string, i.e. with `fgets`, then process that character-by-character, rather than reading and processing characters at the same time.

Comment: To the question itself - no, there is no limit. How do you feed the input though?

Comment: I just copied the numbers and pasted them into terminal.

Comment: So it's your terminal fault. Better redirect from file.

Comment: It's probably the fault of the kernel tty driver's cooked/canonical mode, which has to impose a line length limit to avoid needing unbounded buffer space in the kernel. If the tty were in non-cooked mode, the terminal would probably not prevent you from pasting arbitrarily many characters through it. But yes, OP should use redirection here.

Comment: I bet your copy-paste stopped at 4095 characters.

Comment: What is the result of `printf("%d\n", BUFSIZ);`?